# CSS Issue - Trying to get HTML elements to stay on one line

Tags: html

I'm trying to achieve a layourt like: Search (gif) : TextBox : AjaxLoader (gif) on one line.

I have the following style:

```
<div>           
        <img src='<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/Images/search.gif")%>' alt="Search"/>&nbsp            
        <%= Html.TextBox("SearchTextBox", string.Empty, new { style = "float:left;" })%>   
        <div id="LoadingGif" style="float:left;"></div>    
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>      
</div>
```

The search image is on one line and the textbox and loading gif appear on the next line.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try applying float:left to the image as well ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried <img src='<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/Images/search.gif")%>' style="float:left;"> 

still no joy :(

Answer (score 1):

The last two elements are floated left, but the search gif isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the outer div and floated all elemets left - this works.  Thanks for all your help + 1 to all.

Answer (score 0):

An `<img />` and `<input type="text" />` will be `display:inline` by default so shouldn't need `float:left`.

And you might be better off replacing your `<div id="LoadingGif" style="float:left;"></div>` with either a  tag or an  tag: then you'll have 3 inline elements meaning you can remove the surplus `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` from your HTML :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing divs by spans as such:

```
<div>           
        <img src='<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/Images/search.gif")%>' alt="Search"/>&nbsp            
        <%= Html.TextBox("SearchTextBox", string.Empty, new { style = "float:left;" })%>   
        <span id="LoadingGif" style="float:left;"></span>    
        <span style="clear:both;"></span>      
</div>
```

would work...